# Hide Complete Boot Message from RPI booting

Tags: boot

I am trying to remove boot messages from RPi and want to display a splash screen instead. I succeeded to show a splash screen and removed some boot messages, but it still shows some messages in the console. My cmdline.txt looks like this

```
  logo.nologo dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:VGA8x8 vt.global_cursor_default=0 loglevel=3
```

But while booting it shows these messages on the console

```
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[info] Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel
[ok] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udev
[ok] Synthesizing the initial hot plug events.. done
```

How I can remove this messages from being displayed while booting. I tried different loglevel, still no luck.

Comment: The messages you've shown are not from the kernel, they are from [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init). There are various init systems around used on Raspberry Pi GNU/Linux distros, the two principle ones are Debian's SysV style init, which this looks to be, used on Raspbian wheezy and perhaps Kali (I'm not sure), and Systemd, used on Raspbian jessie and Arch. How you quash init messages at boot depends on which of those you are using, and is better investigated at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), since it is not a pi specific issue.

Comment: A quick solution would be redirecting it to tty console other than tty1 by specifying it in cmdline.txt. (like this one --> `console=tty3`) so that it doesn't get reflected on screen. It works for me (I'm using an HDMI display).

Comment: There are aspects of this question that are very RPi-specific. We should make sure there aren't RPi considerations before discouraging legitimate questions, particularly since we're still in Beta limbo.

Comment: @bobstro The means you mention in your answer are in fact *not* pi specific (beyond being set in `cmdline.txt` instead of a bootloader config, although the former is really a form of the latter), even if you may not recognize it.  However, it's still a decent answer.

Comment: For that to be true, the instructions provided would have to actually work on the RPi. Unless those parameters are included in /boot/cmdline.txt -- which is certainly uncommon if not completely unique among platforms -- instructions found elsewhere may not work at all, regardless of the theory.

Comment: @bobstro I'll tell you exactly what cmdline.txt is.  It's [command line parameters](https://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) passed to the kernel by the bootloader.   The kernel passes some of these on to `init`.  The most significant parameters from your post are `console` and `loglevel`, used by the kernel and potentially init.  Note they are documented in the vanilla source and are **not** specific to the pi.

Comment: And how do you set those parameters on the Raspberry Pi? On every desktop linux system I've used, it's been grub or lilo bootloader or equivalent. On the RPi, it's different. Which is my point. The means by which you pass those parameters -- many of which are specific to the RPi -- is via /boot/cmdline.txt. Would answers about configuring grub really help?

Comment: Right, I'm just clarify what those parameters are.  *Someone who knows this, knows that they are not pi specific, and (hopefully) recognizes that the linux world is orders of magnitude bigger than the pi world, and that a basic rule of online research is to investigate in the broadest context possible, **not** the narrowest.*  By proliferating the idea that these things are pi-specific, you encourage other people to waste their time barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Added console=tty3 to my  cmdline.txt but it still shows some messages like this 
[3.226117] GPIO $bb890000 = 0x24800000
[3.226431] GPIO $bb890004 = 0x24024  I want to hide this too

Answer (score 4):

I have had great success with the following (as far as quiet boot goes, I haven't tried any splash screens yet)

> dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty3 loglevel=0
>   root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes
>   rootwait logo.nologo quiet splash

I will keep it without markdown so its more easily read. For me this works and only displays a grey box with the three dot loading screen then goes straight to the login prompt.

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 raspberrypi tty3
raspberrypi login:
```

If you want tty3 to login automatically:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select Boot Options, Select Desktop/CLI , Select Console AutoLogin

```
sudo cp /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty{1,3}.service
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty3.service
```

Then on the last line edit `DefaultInstance=tty1` to `DefaultInstance=tty3`

Reference File: [cmdline.txt](https://github.com/BaReinhard/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install/blob/master/boot/cmdline.txt)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this video](https://youtu.be/vgJF7cAngUo), this guy got his Model 1B to boot completely silently using Rasbian Wheezy. He seems to be using one fo the recommendations from the comments above and redirect the output to a different console.

Here are the changes he's made to his `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

console=tty3
loglevel=3
vt.global_cursor_default=0
logo.nologo

Comment: That guy is me.

Answer (score 2):

In Jessie, it seems to be enough to comment the lines in `/etc/pam.d/login` that make reference to printing info after successful login.

Just `sudo /etc/pam.d/login` and add a `#` before those uncommented lines.

After this I still have two lines:

> Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 raspberrypi tty1
>
> raspberrypi login: pi (automatic login)

I still wasn't able to get rid of those two...

Comment: I managed to edit/remove "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 raspberrypi tty1" by editing the file `/etc/issue`