# Booting raspberryPi

Tags: raspbian, boot

I have a requirement to hide or remove the "Recovery Screen" completely during boot. I did not find any information related to this. I am unable to move forward. Please guide me or provide me a hint to achieve. I used Raspbian NOOBS.

Comment: What "Recovery Screen" ? What OS did you install?

Comment: I am using Raspian, on boot Raspian always ask for "Recovery Mode" Screen ( press Shift to enter into recovery mode ). I dont want the recovery screen to display everytime when raspian is rebooted.

Comment: Was this installed with noobs?

Comment: @Steve: Yes it is installed with NOOBS

Comment: Please edit your question and add the answers to your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recovery option you mention is part of the noobs boot process. Therefore the simplest solution is probably to create a new SD card with Raspbian without using noobs. The Raspbian disk image can be downloaded from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), and installation instructions are available [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md).

If you want to hide all boot messages and not just the recovery option this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/hide-complete-boot-message-from-rpi-booting?rq=1) provides the details.

Comment: Thank you, as per your instruction. The Recovery screen will not appear on Raspbian without NOOBS.